# OpenCV - GrabCut with custom foreground/background models

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I want to use the GrabCut algorithm implemented on OpenCV.

As shown in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#grabcut) this is the function signature:

```
void grabCut(
    InputArray img, 
    InputOutputArray mask, 
    Rect rect, 
    InputOutputArray bgdModel, // *
    InputOutputArray fgdModel, // *
    int iterCount, 
    int mode=GC_EVAL)
```

The **mode** param, indicates how to initialize the algorithm, either with the **rect** (a rectangle bounding box) or with the **mask** (a matrix whose values correspond to user paintings of the foreground/background regions.

I already have the color models for both the FG and the BG, so ideally I shouldn’t need to provide a mask or a rectangle, but use those models as an initialization (I want to prevent OpenCV to compute new models and use mine instead). I see that **bgdModel** and **fgdModel** parameters somehow contain this model information. Unfortunatelly, **the documentation does not provide any details** on how the model information is stored there.

**Is it possible to populate those models whith existing data and run the method with** `mode=GC_EVAL`**?**, if so, how do I need to encode the models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In opencv/sources/modules/imgproc/src/grabcut.cpp you can have a look how the models (GMMs) are encoded:

```
GMM::GMM( Mat& _model )
{
    const int modelSize = 3/*mean*/ + 9/*covariance*/ + 1/*component weight*/;
    if( _model.empty() )
    {
        _model.create( 1, modelSize*componentsCount, CV_64FC1 );
        _model.setTo(Scalar(0));
    }
    else if( (_model.type() != CV_64FC1) || (_model.rows != 1) || (_model.cols != modelSize*componentsCount) )
        CV_Error( CV_StsBadArg, "_model must have CV_64FC1 type, rows == 1 and cols == 13*componentsCount" );

    model = _model;

    coefs = model.ptr<double>(0);
    mean = coefs + componentsCount;
    cov = mean + 3*componentsCount;

    for( int ci = 0; ci < componentsCount; ci++ )
        if( coefs[ci] > 0 )
             calcInverseCovAndDeterm( ci );
}
```

So you need for every model a cv::Mat of 1 x 65 doubles (componentsCount equals 5). There are 3 means per component because its computing in RGB colorspace. Using GC_EVAL would indeed leave the models intact but I never tried it with pre-computed models.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have looked into the code, but what does those numbers actually mean? how is the model encoded into those values? Passing a populated array is a trivial task, but those values need to make some sense to be useful though.

Answer (score 1):

Even I had a similar problem. This is how I solved it. 
I edited the GC_EVAL condition in the grabcut source code to this -

```
if( mode == GC_EVAL )
   { checkMask( img, mask );
    for( int i = 0; i < iterCount; i++ )
{
    GCGraph<double> graph;
    assignGMMsComponents( img, mask, bgdGMM, fgdGMM, compIdxs );

    constructGCGraph(img, mask, bgdGMM, fgdGMM, lambda, leftW, upleftW, upW, uprightW, graph );
    estimateSegmentation( graph, mask );
    return;    
}
}
```

Notice that the function learnGMMs is not called here. This is done because the Foreground and Background GMMs are precomputed.

You can save models in a .xml file using the following code snippet.

```
 FileStorage fs("mymodels.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
        fs << "BgdModel" << bgdModel;
        fs << "FgdModel" << fgdModel;
fs.release();
```

You can retrieve the models using the following code.

```
FileStorage fs1("mymodels.xml", FileStorage::READ);

        fs1["BgdModel"] >> bgdModel1;

        fs1["FgdModel"] >> fgdModel1;
```

This worked for me.