# How does one provide Foreground and Background model constructed from one image to some other image for performing Grabcut?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv's grabcut.cpp and graphcut.cpp code which calls the function grabcut() . I have to find a way to save the background and foreground models computed from some image and apply it to another image. how do I save the 'bgdmodel' and 'fgdmodel' for future use?

This is the code I have written -

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    // Load an image
    Mat img = imread("1.png",1);
    const Mat* img_0;
    img_0= &img;
    // Create the mask
    Mat mask;
    mask.create( img_0->size(), CV_8UC1);
    mask.setTo( GC_BGD );



    Mat bgdModel, fgdModel;
    Rect rect;
    rect.x=0;
    rect.y=0;
    rect.width=img.cols-1;
    rect.height=img.rows-1;
    (mask(rect)).setTo( Scalar(GC_BGD) );
    grabCut(img, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 1, GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);


    // Save model to file

        FileStorage fs("mymodels.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
        fs << "BgdModel" << bgdModel;
        fs << "FgdModel" << fgdModel;
        fs.release();



    // Load another image
    Mat img1 = imread( "abc.png", 1);
    const Mat* img_1;
    img_1= &img1;
    // Load models from file
    Mat bgdModel1, fgdModel1;
    Mat mask1;


        FileStorage fs1("mymodels.xml", FileStorage::READ);

        fs1["BgdModel"] >> bgdModel1;

        fs1["FgdModel"] >> fgdModel1;

        fs1.release();
    // Create a mask
    mask1.create( img_1->size(), CV_8UC1);
    mask1.setTo( GC_PR_FGD );
    Rect rect1;
    rect1.x=0;
    rect1.y=0;
    rect1.width=0;//img.cols;
    rect1.height=0;//img.rows;
    (mask1(rect1)).setTo( Scalar(GC_BGD) );


    grabCut(img1, mask1, rect1, bgdModel1, fgdModel1, 1, GC_EVAL);




   FileStorage fs2("finalmask.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);

        fs2 << "Final_MASK" << mask1;

        fs2.release();

     for (int i=0;i<img1.rows;i++)
     {
        for(int j=0;j<img1.cols;j++)
        {
            if(mask1.at<uchar>(i,j)==0||mask1.at<uchar>(i,j)==2)
            {
                img1.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = 0;
                img1.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1] = 0;
                img1.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = 0;
            }

        }
     }   


    imshow("Result of Grabcut", img1);
   waitKey(0);


return 0;
}
```

i need to ensure that bgdModel and fgdModel learnt for *image are applied for image1 too.

Comment: I want to segment out tables from a scene. i am learning the table's GMM from another image which is just a table patch. i want to automate the segmentation process (no rectangle required to make)

Comment: i want to do something very similar to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806064/opencv-grabcut-with-custom-foreground-background-models

Comment: I think I got what you mean. fgd and bgd are just `Mat`s. You initialize them using `grabcut` on some image, and then you can reuse these `Mat`s with other images. If you need to store these `Mat`s on a file, just use `FileStorage`

Comment: Thanks @Miki . But I would need a little help in saving the Mat in proper format and also retrieving it properly. further help would be appreciated!!

Comment: When `grabcut` is used with parameter `GC_EVAL` the input models are used, but then are updated internally.

Comment: i edited the GC_EVAL condition to prevent the code from learning GMM again. It is working now :) Thanks @Miki !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the background and foreground models `Mat` using `FileStorage`, and then load them back to use with the next image.

This example should clarify this:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    {
        // Load an image
        Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

        // Create the mask
        Mat1b mask(img.rows, img.cols, uchar(GC_PR_BGD));
        circle(mask, Point(img.cols / 2, img.rows / 2), 20, Scalar(GC_FGD), -1);

        Mat bgdModel, fgdModel;
        grabCut(img, mask, Rect(), bgdModel, fgdModel, 1);

        imshow("Mask", mask);
        waitKey(1);

        // Save model to file
        {
            FileStorage fs("mymodels.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
            fs << "BgdModel" << bgdModel;
            fs << "FgdModel" << fgdModel;
        }
    }

    {
        // Load another image
        Mat3b img = imread("path_to_another_image");

        // Load models from file
        Mat bgdModel, fgdModel;

        {
            FileStorage fs("mymodels.yml", FileStorage::READ);
            fs["BgdModel"] >> bgdModel;
            fs["FgdModel"] >> fgdModel;
        }

        // Create a mask
        Mat1b mask(img.rows, img.cols, uchar(GC_PR_BGD));
        circle(mask, Point(img.cols / 2, img.rows / 2), 20, Scalar(GC_FGD), -1);

        grabCut(img, mask, Rect(), bgdModel, fgdModel, 1);

        imshow("Other Mask", mask);
        waitKey(1);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error - "mymodels.yml(0): Valid XML should start with '<?xml ...?>' in function icvXMLParse"

Comment: @aseembits93 save it as .yml, and load it as a .yml

Comment: It is working now. i was not doing fs.release(). Thanks @Miki

Comment: You usually don't use release, but put the `FileStorage` in a block: `{...}`, so that its destructor is called automatically and the file is closed. However, glad it works. Consider marking as an answer if this solve your problem

Comment: Actually it's not working yet! I'll put up the code. should i put it in comment or in the description?