# How to reuse models from grabcut in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm encountering a similar problem (or the same?) to the one described here: [Reusing models from grabcut in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195532/reusing-models-from-grabcut-in-opencv). However, this issue seems to be corrected according to https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9191. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread("image.jpg")
rect = (0, 773, 517, 1183)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)

mask, bgdModel, fgdModel = cv.grabCut(img, None, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
mask, bgdModel, fgdModel = cv.grabCut(img, mask, None, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv.GC_EVAL)
```

After the first call to grabCut I have the right result in mask (which is great indeed!). However, after the second call to grabCut the mask contains zero values only. I was expecting to have exactly the same result as before. Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding something about how to use cv.GC_EVAL mode? I'm trying to reuse models as in the initial post by ipa [Reusing models from grabcut in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195532/reusing-models-from-grabcut-in-opencv).

I get the same results when using cv.GC_EVAL_FREEZE_MODEL. I'm using opencv-python 4.4.0.42 and python 3.6.

Thanks a lot in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, I'm sharing it with you :). I have replaced the last two lines with the following ones:

```
mask = np.ones(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)*cv.GC_PR_BGD
mask, bgdModel, fgdModel = cv.grabCut(img, mask, None, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv.GC_EVAL_FREEZE_MODEL)
```

HTH,